# sql update command doesnt update the DB

Tags: c#, sql

I have this button updating an empty table cell depending on an ID given in the program.

The code has no errors but doens't update the Table ...

At

```
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",ActiveAthNum);
```

I tried leaving it String and casting it as an int (The table cells are int both ID and Points)

AfRows returns 0... but the Query itself runs perfectly in SQL ...
The ActiveAthNum and PointsGiven Variables have the value that they should.

Code :

```
private void btnSavePoints_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(CONNSTRING);
    cmd4 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SadaTestTable SET Points = @pts WHERE id = @id");
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ActiveAthNum);
    PointsGiven = Convert.ToInt32(tbPointsGiven.Text);
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pts", PointsGiven);
    cmd4.Connection = con;
    int AfRows;
    con.Open();
    AfRows = cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `id` column? And what is the type and value of `ActiveAthNum`? And of course, don't use `.AddWithValue`. [It may generate unexpected results.](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: check @id value. are you passing a correct value?

Comment: id column is Int Points is int too, ActiveAthNum is casted to Int previously in the code when it was given value

Comment: Can you show how you cast `ActiveAthNum` as an `int`.  If it is a `string` you should be parsing it to an `int`.

Comment: @frcake What is your `cmd4` looks like when you add your parameter values? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: Improvements: always use the correct type(which is `int`), all the more if you use `AddWithValue` which needs to infer the type from the value. Also use the `using` statement for the connection to ensure that it gets closed as soon as possible.

Comment: public int ActiveAthNum = 0, PointsGiven = 0; (at the start of the program)    
ActiveAthNum = Convert.ToInt32(tbAthNum.Text); *cast

Comment: Run sql profiler if you can and see what sql command is actually hitting the database.

Comment: @frcake Id say right off hand 0 is not a valid id in your table.

Comment: Do not use AddWithValue use Parameters.Add and specify db type like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx). Surround sqlconnection in using statement

Comment: @frcake FYI, using `Convert` is parsing, not casting.  Using the correct terminology will make asking questions less confusing to others.

Comment: Have you tried without `WHERE` clause - only for test? Maybe the value for ID does not exist in table.

Comment: @i486 you shouldn't recommend UPDATE without WHERE. You know what that will do right?

Comment: @Crowcoder Of course, I know "what that will do". It is not very hard to guess to run this on test copy of the DB.

Comment: Also, cmd4.CommandType should be CommandType.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really ought to put that DB call into a Try...Catch...Finally block.

What's the default language for your DB? A long time ago I saw this type of error (no update but no error) when the DB language was set to US-EN instead of "Database Default."

The DB would throw an "error" about the default language being changed, but it didn't trigger an error in my ASP code. Something about the error code didn't register as an error - I had to code for that specific error number in order to get around it. I've only seen this twice, but at two different companies...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in type of ID parameter. Try specifying correct DbType:

```
cmd4.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Char); //set proper type as in table
cmd4.Parameters["id"].Value = "";
```

Comment: cmd4.Parameters.Add("id", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ""; : )

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ActiveAthNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

### probleby the problem is because you havent specified the data type

```
private void btnSavePoints_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(CONNSTRING);
    cmd4 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SadaTestTable SET Points = @pts WHERE id = @id",con);
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Datatype.Char);//if the datatype in the database is char but if the data type in the database is int then is datatype.int
    PointsGiven = Convert.ToInt32(tbPointsGiven.Text);
    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pts", PointsGiven);
     try
   {
         con.open();//here open my connection 
         cmd4.connection = con;  
        Afrows = cmd4.ExecutenonQuery();//Execute my query
   }
  catch
   {
      throw;//possible exceptions in the system
   }
  finally
   {
       con.Close();//closing connections
   }


}
```